# Pandoc: Converting images from Markdown to Latex

Tags: latex, markdown, pandoc

I have the following `mwe.md` markdown-file

```
### Short version for testing

    <div style="text-align: center;">
    <img src="myimage.jpeg" style="width: 200px; height: auto;"  
        title="myimage.jpeg"/> 
    </div>
```

Converting with `pandoc mwe.md -o mwe.html` and then `pandoc mwe.html -o mwe.tex` gives

```
\subsubsection{Short version for
testing}\label{short-version-for-testing}

\includegraphics{myimage.jpeg}
```

What to do to get

```
\subsubsection{Short version for
testing}\label{short-version-for-testing}

\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=200]{myimage.jpeg}
\end{center}
```

Have I to write a `filter` to get this? If I convert `mwe.html` to `PDF`, then the image is centered but to big.